# How to scroll LI items in a fixed height UL?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, html-lists

Here is my example HTML.

And I want to have scroll for my LI items.

Which are of 2 levels. Means, I want to apply class on every UL.

So how can I do that. By using JQuery or CSS tweaking.

PS: I am using this [example](http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/dropdown.simple.horizontal.html).

```
<ul id="nav" class="dropdown">
<li class="dir">
    Item_Root
    <ul>
        <li class="dir">
            Item_1_Level
            <ul>
                <li>Item_Level_2</li>
                <li>Item_Level_2</li>
                <li>Item_Level_2</li>
                <li>.... up to N items</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item_Level_1</li>
        <li>Item_Level_1</li>
        <li>Item_Level_1</li>
        <li>Item_Level_1</li>
        <li>.... up to N items</li>
    </ul>
</li>

 </ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What went wrong? What size should the containing-`ul` be? The example you linked to is a drop-down/fly-out menu; how does that relate to what you want?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With your posted mark-up, and the best guess I could make of the intent of your question (your title doesn't really match the example you linked to), I came up with this:

```
#nav {
    width: 12em;
    height: 20em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

li {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul ul {
    text-indent: 1em;
}

ul ul ul {
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zkutx/).

Comment: Thanks David, I linked the example because I am following that. And I could have n number of items in my LI. And same is the case with 2nd level UL. Actually a lot of LI items cause scroll at my webpage. I dont want to let browser scroll. But My items in LI. And for more I want to have mousemove scroll up and scroll down. I got a hard time finding help to scroll my LI items in UL. I appreciate if I can see help over it.

Comment: Do you want the second-level `ul` items to be in the same 'box' as the first-level `ul`, or do you want them to fly-out, as it in the example you link to? Or do you want them hidden, and *then* appear in the same 'box' as the first-level `ul` items?

Comment: David I want them flyout. And have the same behavior of scroll in them. Similar to example. The only thing with example is, it does not have enough value to have that scenario. Level 1 menu will drop down and level2 menu will flyout. How I can achieve it. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 7):

The main idea is to set a fixed height for the UL list, and add

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Maybe you'll also need to tweak the width of UL, since the scroll bar will need some extra space.